# How to push individual record data to external DB via Quick Action button via LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, callout, quickaction, winter22

**LeadCalloutToDB Apex:**

```
public without sharing class LeadCalloutToDB{

    @future(callout = true)
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static void callDBgateway(String recordId){
    
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    
        //Please set the endpoint of API gateway which we are going to create in later section
        request.setEndpoint('<endpoint url>');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    
        // Set the body as a JSON object
    
        request.setBody('{"id": "'+recordId+'"}');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        System.debug('response==='+response.getBody());
    
        // Parse the JSON response
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
            response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        }
    }
}
```

**LeadToDB LWC:**

```
import {LightningElement, api, wire} from 'lwc';
import callDBgateway from '@salesforce/apex/LeadAWSCallout.callDBgateway';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Name';


export default class LeadToDB extends LightningElement {
    @api invoke() {
        console.log("Hi, I'm an action.");
    }

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId'})
    leads;

    get name() {
        return getFieldValue(this.lead.data, NAME_FIELD);
    }

    @wire(callDBgateway, {recordId: '$recordId' })
    wiredDBGateway({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.db = data;
 
            //This is where we fire our toast, you can perform more logic here
            this.fireSuccessToast();
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        }
    }

    fireSuccessToast(){
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "WOAHH",
            message: 'You just submitted this record to AWS',
            variant: "success",
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

With this code I managed to have the Quick Action button visible on the Lead Record Page layout. However, when I pressed the button, nothing happened, not even a debug callout on dev console. So I'm not even sure it is sending anything? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things stand out here.

First, you apparently forgot this in your class:

```
@api recordId;
```

Without that, your LWC won't get the record Id from context.

Second, you should call your Apex imperatively, rather than trying to wire it.

```
@api async invoke() {
    try {
        this.db = await callDBgateway({recordId:this.recordId})
        this.fireSuccessToast();
    } catch(e) {
        // Deal with the error here
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}
```